# Row-wise data reading in Python using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, openpyxl

I am trying to obtain a list in python by the format [[a,b], [c,d],...]

As an example, for two columns below in excel:

```
     R1   R2
     1    2
     6    2
     0    9
     3    2
     4    1
     5    6
```

I should obtain a list = [[1,2], [6,2], [0, 9], [3,2], [4,1], [5,6]]

The code I have is shown below:

```
    R = []
    # iterate over column
    for col in range(min_column+3, max_column+1): #location of the data
    # u_need reads in the resource needed for each activity
      u_need = []
      # iterate over row
      for row in range(2, max_row+1): #row 1 is not included
         # loop until blank space is encountered
         if (sheet.cell(row,col).value is not None):
             u_need.append(sheet.cell(row,col).value);

      R.append(u_need)

    print(f'R = {R}')
```

but the result gives me something like this:

```
    R = [[1, 6, 0, 3, 4, 5], [2, 2, 9, 2, 1, 6]]
```

Is there a way I could change this? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using xlrd package to read the excel worksheets

```
import xlrd 

# my own excel sheet location which contains your data  
loc = "a.xlsx"

# opening workbook 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
# selecting the first worksheet
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
lst = []
# not including the first row
for i in range(1,sheet.nrows):
    dummy = []
    for j in range(sheet.ncols):
        # appending the columns with the same row to dummy list
        dummy.append(sheet.cell_value(i, j))
    # appending the dummy list to the main list
    lst.append(dummy)
print(f"lst = {lst}") # output  lst = [[1.0, 2.0], [6.0, 2.0], [0.0, 9.0], [3.0, 2.0], [4.0, 1.0], [5.0, 6.0]]
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it while still using openpyxl. I think the difference from my first code was I use to loop over the column first before the row. That is why the data being read are column-wise. Thank you so much!!